# How to handle INF in Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran77

I have a distribution function f(x), saved in a file with two columns (first column is x, second column is f(x)), e.g.

```
..
1.667  0.815083333
1.668  0.810443333
1.669  0.813403333
1.67  0.810623333
1.671  0.804236667
1.672  0.805286667
...
```

Of this function, I need to take minus the logarithm. Since the distribution might be 0 for some value of x, the logarithm might be infinity for some value of x. This way, when I write `-log(f(x))`  on a file I might get

```
3.894  13.8155106
3.895  13.8155106
3.896  INF
3.897  INF
3.898  INF
```

and if I eventually read the file then the program will exit with an error

```
invalid number: incomprehensible list input
apparent state: unit 17 named fort.17
last format: list io
lately reading direct formatted external IO
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is the best way to rewrite the program so that it can handle reading/writing `-log(0)`?

Comment: It would be good manners to explain why you would downvote my question, so that I can ask better ones in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to just use a mock value for infinity, so that we only take the logarithm when `f(x)>epsilon`, with `epsilon` a suitably low threshold, and use a suitably big value otherwise.

```
     do ir = 0, nbb
        if (targetdbb(ir) .gt. 1.d0e-10) then
           eibb(ir) = -log(targetdbb(ir))
        else
           eibb(ir) = 100000
        endif
     enddo
```

this is an ad hoc implementation that will solve the problem, provided we can accept to lose any difference between `f(x)=0` and `f(x)<1e-10`.